# execute command in go without storing the command in a .exe file

Tags: windows-10, memory, code-execution

I am trying to do a go program to execute a `.exe` file, but without be actually a `.exe` file. The idea is to read the executable from a `.txt` file and decode it (it is in base64). Once I hava that code stored in a variale, I want to execute it directecly, without having to write it in disk.

In this line why do you decode and store the code in the variable `decodedDataBytes:`

```
decodedDataBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(decodedData)
```

Then I write it in a temp file and execute it like this:

```
tempFilePath := "temp.exe"
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(tempFilePath, decodedDataBytes, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("D:\temp.exe") 
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

This works just fine, but I need to do it without storing the code in the file `temp.exe`.

How can I do this??

I am using go, but if this can be done with other language, I accept ideas too.

Comment: Why does it have to be an exe? Most languages will just let you eval(base64_decode(string)) for dynamic execution

Comment: @wireghoul Most _scripting_ languages will, and some languages with a heavy-duty runtime that includes an interpreter also will. For compiled languages, that doesn't work at all. You might be able to load intermediate language (for languages that use a bytecode, like Java or the .NET family) directly into the runtime, but a language like Go that is fully compiled and indeed statically linked won't offer that option.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a Windows API called *VirtualAlloc* to allocate executable memory, write the decoded bytes to that memory, and then execute it. Here's an example of a code I wrote that would help you achieve this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // Read the base64 string from the .txt file
    base64Data := "BASE64_ENCODED_STRING" // Replace with your actual base64 string

    // Decode the base64 string
    decodedData, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64Data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Allocate executable memory
    executableMemory, err := syscall.VirtualAlloc(0, uintptr(len(decodedData)), syscall.MEM_COMMIT, syscall.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Copy the decoded bytes to the executable memory
    executableMemorySlice := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&syscall.Slice{Data: executableMemory, Len: len(decodedData), Cap: len(decodedData)}))
    copy(executableMemorySlice, decodedData)

    // Execute the code in the executable memory
    syscall.Syscall(executableMemory, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    // Free the allocated memory
    syscall.VirtualFree(executableMemory, 0, syscall.MEM_RELEASE)
}
```

In this code, I use the syscall.VirtualAlloc function to allocate executable memory, syscall.VirtualFree to free the allocated memory, and syscall.Syscall to execute the code in the allocated memory. The unsafe package is used to convert the allocated memory to a byte slice for copying the decoded bytes.

Comment: This will work for short snippets of machine code, but not for "an .exe file" that the question asks about, which is presumably in PE (Portable Executable) format and requires imports and fixups.

Comment: Also `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is mostly prohibited (so-called `W^X` feature), it may be necessary to change the page permission between writing and executing.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply "not a .EXE file", there's an easy option: use literally any other extension (or none at all). The only thing that makes ".EXE" special is that it's one of a small list of file extensions that the Windows shell (via the `ShellExecute` family of APIs) will by default attempt to execute directly rather than attempting to open a handler for. However, there's no need to use `ShellExecute` for anything, especially if you're doing this programmatically. You can invoke the `CreateProcess` family of APIs on literally any file system object, and if it has the Execute permission for the relevant security principal (user) and is readable as a PE executable file, it will work. The extension can be anything you want, or missing entirely.

In fact, CMD always tried to `CreateProcess` a file before anything else, if you pass a file as a bare command. As a result, the following works just fine (in `cmd.exe`, not Powershell or any other shell except maybe `command.com` if for some reason you're on a 32-bit system) to launch the Windows calculator:

```
> copy %windir%\System32\calc.exe .\bogus.txt
> bogus.txt
```

Normally passing a ".txt" file to CMD will open your default text editor (Notepad, unless you changed the default), but only because the shell falls back to `ShellExecute` after `CreateProcess` fails. Since you're writing your own program, here, you can just call `CreateProcess` and never consider `ShellExecute` at all.

If you want to create the process directly from a memory buffer... this is possible, but it is definitely harder. One option is to create a process in a suspended state, and pointing at some arbitrary executable (even your own current executable), and then swap out the executable image before calling `ResumeThread` to get the process going. [This question has an answer discussing that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305203/createprocess-from-memory-buffer). Alternatively, the at least one of the NT syscalls `NtCreateProcessEx` or `NtCreateUserProcess` should allow creating a process from a memory section, though I've never done so and don't have a handy tutorial for doing so (note that third-party code is not expected to call those syscalls directly; they are poorly documented and subject to changing behavior). You could also try using an object that is not technically a file, such as a [named memory mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) and passing the path (note that it's not a *file* path) to the standard `CreateProcess` APIs, though I don't know if that will work either.